# How to locate CKEditor in Selenium Webdriver, and what is iframe and body in CK Editor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpAQY.png)
I have found the one code which is:

```
driver.get("https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/");
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
WebElement tinymce = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
tinymce.clear();
tinymce.sendKeys("Hello, ckeditor!");
```

What is iframe? what kind of TagName is this.
What is body? what kind of Tagname is this.

Simply I am always using Xpath, ID, Value.
The code is provided "iframe and body" in this tag what i have to insert.
Please help
Thank U...

Comment: Can across several issues with such editor, the most consistent solution was using javascript to set the text value.
please provide the hmtl markup if you need further help

Comment: Hi I am inserted the image in upper question please click on "See image" file for HTML code.....and thank u for your reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the following should set any text into the editor textarea.

Hope this helps.

```
    String someText ="text";
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriverInstance;
    js.executeScript("CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData('"+someText+"')");
```

Comment: Hi, Zack Thank u so much for your reply,, it finally worked, thank u sooo much.....

Comment: And how do you test (assert) a text in a CKEditor?